# Heroku bonsai index naming bug

Tags: heroku, elasticsearch

I'm using Heroku Bonsai for hosted elastic search via the Tire gem for rails. I'm working on a relatively high-traffic site and this issue is ONLY manifesting on bonsai instances that we've set up (for QA environments) in the last couple of weeks (so make sure your instance is that fresh if you try to reproduce). I'm getting a "502 Bad Gateway" error in the following narrow circumstance:

```
curl -XPOST http://[your-bonsai-endpoint-domain]/mysite_qa_users
```

HOWEVER, if I instead do:

```
curl -XPOST http://[your-bonsai-endpoint-domain]/mysite_qa_user
```

...or even

```
curl -XPOST http://[your-bonsai-endpoint-domain]/mysite_qa_products
```

...everything succeeds, so this seems to only be happening in the narrow first condition for us (creating an index called mysite_qa_users) as if there's a bug with the specific naming scheme "[something]_qa_users". Even changing it to "mysite_staging_users", for instance, seems to succeed. Our app has a very large user base and we'd rather not change fundamental things such as our index naming scheme just to accommodate a bug with our PaaS provider that, it would seem, should not be happening. Does anybody have insight on this?

Comment: Nick, you should contact Bonsai support or https://twitter.com/nz_, probably the fastest way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Karmi's right, this is a support question for support@bonsai.io — we've since got this one all sorted out.

Comment: Odd coincidence that the user's name here is Nick Z…!